# Problem with deserialization in Blazor project

Tags: c#, .net-core, json.net, blazor

When I try to deserialize JSON string to class I've got an exception,
I use `Newtonsoft.Json`

I do it like this:

```
MyClass response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(JsonString);
```

And same code with the same data in C# .net Core API project with `Newtonsoft.Json` work's well, but in `Blazor` project have an exception

> blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM: Unhandled Exception:
>   blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load
>   type of field 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken:_parent' (1) due to: Could
>   not resolve type with token 010000f5 from typeref (expected class
>   'System.Collections.Specialized.INotifyCollectionChanged' in assembly
>   'mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e') assembly:mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
>   type:System.Collections.Specialized.INotifyCollectionChanged
>   member:(null)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's this bug https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/1692

You need to disable linking https://blazor.net/docs/host-and-deploy/configure-linker.html#disable-linking-with-an-msbuild-property

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <BlazorLinkOnBuild>false</BlazorLinkOnBuild>
</PropertyGroup>
```